# MVC 3 Razor - Ajax.BeginForm OnSuccess

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to MVC and I'm trying to update my page after I submit my form; but it's not working.  I'm only trying to hide the form, and show the contents of a div OnSuccess.

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#confirmation').hide();
    });

    function MessageConfirmation() {
        $('#confirmation').show('slow');
        $('#contactForm').hide('slow');
    }

</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "MessageConfirmation" }))
{
<fieldset id="contactForm">
    <legend>Message</legend>
    <p>
        @Html.Label("Email", "Email"): @Html.TextBox("Email")
    </p>
    <p>
        @Html.Label("Subject", "Subject"): @Html.TextBox("Subject")
    </p>
    <p>
        @Html.Label("Message", "Message"): @Html.TextArea("Message")
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </p>
</fieldset>

<p id="confirmation" onclick="MessageConfirmation()">
    Thanks!!!
</p>
}
```

Any alternate solutions / ideas are most welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

*Not working* is a problem description that's more adapted to people that don't know/care about how computer works and not software developers. Software developers usually describe precisely the problem they are having. They post the exact error message/exception stack trace they are having.

This being said you are asking for alternative solutions, here's mine: don't use any `MS Ajax.* helpers`, use jquery directly and unobtrusively, like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#confirmation').hide();
        $('form').submit(function() {
            $('#confirmation').show('slow');
            $(this).hide('slow');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset id="contactForm">
        <legend>Message</legend>
        <p>
            @Html.Label("Email", "Email"): 
            @Html.TextBox("Email")
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.Label("Subject", "Subject"): 
            @Html.TextBox("Subject")
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.Label("Message", "Message"): 
            @Html.TextArea("Message")
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<p id="confirmation">
    Thanks!!!
</p>
```

Notice how the `confirmation` paragraph has been externalized from the form.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Apologies for the vagueness of the post.  I am a Software Developer with a keen interest in Stella Artois.  However, the form validation is not firing.  How does the client side know if the method is successful?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - would you mind providing me with reason(s) to avoid the `MS Ajax.*` helpers? Are your reasons applicable to MVC4 as well?

Comment: @kyle.stearns, you have far greater control of the AJAX request when writing it yourself, and yes, my reasons are applicable in MVC4 as well.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Thanks. I've always felt that the code generated by the helpers is very bloated and would typically rather write it myself. I'm in a situation where I am required to use it but I'd recommend avoiding using them as well.

Comment: +1 (especially for the first paragraph of your answer)

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you have all the correct js files referenced in your project?
In MVC3, they have moved away from the MS Ajax files. If I remember right - the unobtrusive javascript should be enabled by default, so you should reference the following files: jquery.js, jquery.validate.js, jquery.valudate.unobtrusive.js, jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

With these files references - you should be fine.

P.S. There's a very good blog post by Brad Wilson explaining the details of unobtrusive ajax in MVC3, and how it all works.
Check it out here: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-ajax.html

Comment: Thanks Artion,  I have now included the js files, and the form is validating, but how does the client side know if the method is successful?

Comment: What do you mean? That's a pretty vague question =/

Comment: If you have a validateable ajax form, I think usually you would return the form's partial back, so that the validation messages will be shown on the form's result, or a success partial, if the form post was successful. At least that's how I'd do it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can get to your action method.  Also add a failure handler and see if its returning a failure too.

The unobtrusive features must be enabled too, and you must add in the MVC unobtrusive AJAX scripts for MVC 3 and razor.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery trigger

```
$("#confirmation").trigger('click');
```

Because you have a onclick method on the div