# Callbacks on Ajax.BeginForm don't work

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, callback, razor

I'm having difficulty getting the callbacks to work for a form.  I have something like this:

```
<script>
function VendorCreated() {
  alert('ok');
}
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Vendor", new AjaxOptions {
    UpdateTargetId = ViewBag.TargetId, 
    HttpMethod = "Post", 
    OnSuccess="VendorCreated",
    })) {
```

upon submission my function never gets created.  If I use:

```
OnSuccess="alert('ok')"
```

it works fine.  I've also tried:

```
OnSuccess="function() { VendorCreated(); }"
```

but I get a runtime error.  Others are having this issue but I've found no resolution, see [MVC 3 Razor - Ajax.BeginForm OnSuccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927479/mvc-3-razor-ajax-beginform-onsuccess) and [Ajax.BeginForm OnBegin confirmation Via jquery modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572573/ajax-beginform-onbegin-confirmation-via-jquery-modal/5904928#5904928).

If I look at the IE debugger (F12) I don't see a script tag in the code generated... what's the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I've narrowed the problem down... the code above is generated by a view which gets loaded into a DIV in another view by jQuery.  I've recently discovered that I can include a view within another view using @Html.Action() and doing so seems to resolve the problem above.  I now get callbacks!

for anyone with the inclination, an explanation of why one works and not the other would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including `jquery.unobtrusive.ajax.js` in your page?

Comment: yes, otherwise I wouldn't get a callback at all (I know because I didn't have it included before so I got no callback... now I get a callback but only as indicated above)