# Callbacks on Ajax.BeginForm don't work right

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, callback, razor

why do I always have so much trouble...?  given that I didn't solve the problem in my [other article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905191/callbacks-on-ajax-beginform-dont-work), I decided to just code the javascript right into the values... so I have:

```
OnSuccess="alert('ok')",
OnFailure="alert('failed')",
```

so my problem is the submission works fine; a record gets inserted into the database and I get a callback... but I get the wrong callback!  I get a failure even though the record got inserted.  heeeeelp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I figured out a few things:

1. OnFailure="handleError" is the correct way to do this (see the other article I mentioned for resolution)
2. ajaxContext didn't have a get_response() method because I was actually hooking up the function to the OnComplete event instead (my bad)!  once hooked up to the OnSuccess, I get my controller's method Json return value natively
3. I was getting the OnSuccess handler called when the database entry was failing.  this is because my controller method was try{} catch{}ing and therefore never failed! me being dopey :(

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to read data from the response to figure out why it's considered a failure:

```
OnFailure="handleError",
```

...

```
function handleError(ajaxContext) {
    var response = ajaxContext.get_response();
    var statusCode = response.get_statusCode();
    alert("Sorry, the request failed with status code " + statusCode);
}
```

Alternatively, use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and look at the response. Make sure the status code, content type and content are all as expected.

Comment: 1. I don't understand why OnFailure is a function call as opposed to a function name... I thought it was supposed to be OnFailure="handleError"?
2. ajaxContent doesn't seem to contain a get_response() method... it contains a responseText which is a string representation of the object my controller method returns (and which I can't dereference).  it also contains fail, done, complete, success and error, all of which are methods that return the object itself...
I'm using the latest version of the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js library right from the Microsoft CDN so what could be the issue?

Comment: My bad, I copy/pasted. Fixed it - should be a function name (I believe). Check the content/content-type/status code with Fiddler to make sure it all looks correct.