# "Unable to get value of the property 'split': object is null or undefined" error in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, maskededitextender

I am trying to use ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit's MaskedEditExtender Control (with MaskedEditValidator) in my web application. The control works fine in Google Chrome but IE9 throws a *"Unable to get value of the property 'split': object is null or undefined"* error while loading the page that contains the MaskedEditExtender controls.
The Visual Studio debugger breaks into MaskedEdit.MaskedEditBehavior.debug.js at the following statements:

```
var partdt = arr[0];
var parttm = arr[1];
if (parttm.split(" ").length == 2) 
{
    parttm += " " + parttm.split(" ")[1];  // breaks here
}
partdt = this.ConvFmtDate(partdt,loadFirst);
```

I have also tried using the

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787245/ie9-javascript-error-script5007-unable-to-get-value-of-the-property-ui-objec) but it did not work. I am also using JQuery 1.4.2 in my application. Any Ideas??

Comment: It looks like `arr[1]` is `null` or `undefined`. Maybe you can trace where that value comes from?

Answer (score 1):

- Did you recently convert your web application from MVC 2 to MVC 3?
- If so, are you using [unobtrusive Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4927628/109941)?

Here's [an excellent explanation from Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-ajax.html).